# How to set pts when video stream has b frame in ffmpeg library?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libavformat

We know that when the video stream has IBBP gop structure, the presentation/decompress timestamps should like below:

```
frame : 0 1 2 3

        I P B B

pts   : 0 3 1 2

dts   : 0 1 2 3
```

but FFmpeg requires that `pts` must be larger or equal than `dts`, so the frame2 & frame3's `pts` is invalid (smaller than dts).

So how I adjust the `pts`?

Comment: Add an offset to each PTS. For example 2. Then the pts would be 2, 5,3,4. And keep DTS the same.

Comment: OK,so can I add negative offset to DTS,and keep PTS the same?

Comment: Yes, assuming the container can handle negative DTS, some can not.

Comment: Another question : If I mux video & audio,I add an offset to video's pts,to keep av sync,should I also add the same offet to audio's pts?